# Angular : Listen and display data I got in a service

Tags: angular

I've a component (research field + button) which use a service (the API call) to get some data from an API. Now I want to display these data from an other component (the result component)

search.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    searchOffer(type: string, params: {}) {
        const headers = new Headers({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*','Content-Type':'application/json'});
        return this.http.post(`http://localhost/${type}`, params, {headers: headers})
        .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                const data = response.json();
                return data;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

search.component. ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchService } from '../search.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  keyword: string;

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }
  onSearch() {
    const params :{} = {query: this.keyword}
    this.searchService.searchOffer('search', params)
    .subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

result.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchService } from '../search.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-result',
  templateUrl: './result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./result.component.css']
})
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }
}
```

I edit to include the whole code for the 3 component implied

And I don't know how I can access it. And I need to know each time it changes..

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Use angular `service` module to pass the data from one component to another and use `observable` to observe the changes.

Comment: You should add a public/private member to the search service class to be shared across components. And accessor describtors in every compoennt to behave reactively on state changes. Doing so you can prevent stale data. Dont use the Observable/Subject solutions only. Use getters to bind to public service members to be reactive on state changes! For example: get search() {
    return this.searchService.searchResult; //public member
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thank you all for your time! I was totally stuck. I think I've found the appropriate answer to my case:

First I added an EventEmitter to my search.service.ts

```
dataUpdated = new EventEmitter<{}>();
```

Then I call this event when I request data in my search.component.ts

```
this.searchService.searchOffer('search', params).subscribe(
  (response) => { 
      console.log(response);
      this.data = response;
      this.searchService.dataUpdated.emit(this.data); 
  },(error) => console.log(error)
);
```

and last I subscribe to my event in result.component.ts

```
constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
this.searchService.dataUpdated.subscribe(
  (data: {}) => console.log(data)
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

service.ts

```
getData(type){
  return this.http.post(`http://localhost/${type}`, params, {headers: headers}).pipe(
  .map(
    (response: Response) => {
      const data = response.json();
      return data;
     }
   ));
}
```

component.ts

```
constructor(private service: YourServiceClass)

  this.service.getData(type)
        .subscribe((resp: any) => {
            this.data = resp
        }, error => {
  });
```

.html

```
{{data | json}}
```

Comment: I think the problem will be that my html bound to another component. so component.ts get the data but I want to display in result.html. I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the service from parent component and pass the data to the child component for display as input. 
Implement `OnChanges` in child component so that it will know whenever the input changes.

**search.component.ts** :

```
this.searchService.searchOffer('search', params).subscribe(
    (response) => { 
        console.log(response);
        this.data = response; 
    },(error) => console.log(error)
);
```

**search.component.html** :

```
<app-child [data]="data"></app-child>
```

**result.component.ts** :

```
@Input('data') result : any

ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('Data changed')
    // Call your custom function
}
```

**result.component.html** :

```
{{result|json}}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tv2h46

Comment: I think it's pretty close, but I don't want my result to be a child of my search. so how can I pass data to result?

Comment: @Unpuzz I believe you have another parent component in which search and result components are children. In that case, when you click the button in search component, fire an event to the parent in which you can query the data. This data will automatically update in the result component.

Comment: @Unpuzz I have updated the demo. [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tv2h46](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tv2h46). Search component fires an event passing the string to be used for searching. You can use the string to query data from parent or pass the string to the child itself and query from there.

Answer (score 0):

use BehaviorSubject in service :

```
private data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>();
public _data$ = this.data$.asObservable();


searchOffer(type: string, params: {}) {
 return this.http.post(`http://localhost/${type}`, params, {headers: headers})
  .map(
   (response: Response) => {
    const data = response.json();

    // store data here
    this.data$.next(data);
    return data;
   }
  );
}
```

then in result component :

```
this.searchService._data$.subscribe(data => {
 // get data here
})
```

Everytime you can API, components which subscribed to _data$ will received new data

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to your **http.post** method in your component.
The solution of Adrita is good but:

- If you subscribe in a component don't forget to unsubcribe in a [onDestroy](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy) function.

An alternative way is to use the async pipe to subscribe to an **Observable** into a template:

component.ts

```
let datas: Observable<any>;  
constructor(private service: YourServiceClass) { // inject your service into the constructor
   this.datas = service.getData(); //reference to your service
}
```

component.html

```
<div>{{datas | async | json}}</div> // display data

<div *ngFor="let data of (datas | async)"> // iterate on async datas
  <h1>{{data}}</h1>
</div>
```

Two advantages for this technique:

- Angular unsubscribe for you via the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to avoid memory leak
- You keep your component code more clear, specially if the datas need to be handle by the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the app-search  and app-result components in a parent component. Put an Output in the app search component and return the data when your search is finished. Then use the response in result component. In the parent component you need to define a searchResults variable. In the result component use the ngOnChange angular lifecycle hook to catch when the data Input content changes.

```
<app-search (onSearch)="searchResults = $event"></app-search>
<app-result [data]="searchResults"><app-search>
```

Search component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onSearch: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter();
  keyword: string;

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }
  onSearch() {
    const params :{} = {query: this.keyword}
    this.searchService.searchOffer('search', params)
    .subscribe(
      (response) => this.onSearch.emit(response);
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }

}
```

Result component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-result',
  templateUrl: './result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./result.component.css']
})
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input data: any[] = [];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // Each time triggers when the data Input content changes
  }
}
```